# Adding an id to React/Gatsby component for hash link

Tags: reactjs, anchor, router, gatsby

I have a link in a nav-bar that takes me to an anchor on the index page. Currently I don't know how to put an id onto the component, so I have to wrap the component in a div and give it an id for it to work. Ideally, I would like to simply put the anchor on the component itself.

This works fine for me, but I'm wondering if this is the way to do an anchor with React/Gatsby or is there a better way?

```js
//Navbar, which is part of Layout
export default class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavContainer>
        <Menu>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Events</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Mentorship</li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/#join-us">Join Us</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </Menu>
      </NavContainer>
    )
  }
}

//Homepage
const IndexPage = ({ data, location }) => {
  const { site, events, about, features, blogs } = data
  const eventsEdges = events.edges
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div id="join-us">
        <JoinUs /> //Can't do <JoinUs id="join-us"/>
      </div>
      <BlogList blogs={blogs} fromIndex={true} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `id` as a `props` to your `JoinUs` component.
First of all, do `<JoinUs id="join-us" />`. Now, `id` is a props of your component.

#### JoinUs component

```
const JoinUs = ({ id }) => (
    <div id={id}>
        ...Your component stuff
    </div>
);
```

#### Other method

```
import React from 'react'

class JoinUs extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id={this.props.id}>
                ... Your component stuff
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default JoinUs
```

The two methods are similar but the first one is more concise. 
The line `JoinUs = ({ id }) ...` allows you to access and destructure props. You get property `id` from your `props`. Now, you don't have to wrap your component in a `div` with an anchor

More information here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment